# React Cannot Start Project - 'craco' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: reactjs, dependency-management, npm-start, craco

is anyone able to tell me why I cannot start up my website project on the development server?

I've cloned a file on Windows 10, this used to work fine on my Mac OS ... before it died :'(Feel free to try the project: https://github.com/EMDevelop/j2c

When I run `npm start`, I get the following message

```
> just2connect@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c
> craco start

'craco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! just2connect@0.1.0 start: `craco start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the just2connect@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T16_11_19_513Z-debug.log
```

**This is strange because** I have `"craco": "0.0.3"` as a dependency, and `"start": "craco start"` as a script within my `package.json`.

I also have the `craco.config` file within the project, and `@craco` folder in the `node_modules` folder.

When I then try and install craco again (`npm i @craco/craco`) and run `npm start`, i get the below error asking me to install the dependencies:

```
C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c>npm i @craco/craco
npm WARN bootstrap@4.6.0 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.16.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN radium@0.25.2 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-coverflow@0.2.20 requires a peer of react@^16.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@3.2.0 requires a peer of react-native-vector-icons@>7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-elements@3.2.0 requires a peer of react-native-safe-area-context@^3.1.9 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-ratings@7.3.0 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-native-size-matters@0.3.1 requires a peer of react-native@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-only-when@1.0.2 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-only-when@1.0.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-particles-js@3.4.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-swipeable@5.5.1 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0-0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-testimonial@1.0.0 requires a peer of react@^16.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c\node_modules\.bin\craco
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c\node_modules\.bin\craco: is outside C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c\node_modules\@craco\craco and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c\node_modules\.bin\craco
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T16_29_51_457Z-debug.log
```

**This is strange also because** I have most of these dependencies inside of the `node_modules` folder (and `package.json`):

[image: Packages.Json Screenshot]

I'm concerned about just recklessly forcing craco to replace the old version, and will I then have to do that for every dependency it has given me the warning for? most of which dependencies already exist.

Then when I try and run `npm start` again, it gives me the error as if I never had craco installed again:

```
C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c>npm start

> just2connect@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Ed\Desktop\Coding\React\j2c
> craco start

'craco' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! just2connect@0.1.0 start: `craco start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the just2connect@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ed\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-26T16_30_25_218Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! pulling my hair out, I'm new to Windows.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me

```
npm install @craco/craco --save
```

Comment: I've tried that, reopened the terminal again and still says 'craco not found' ...

Answer (score 2):

This is **Tailwind css** specific error with **React Applications.**

Since Create React App doesn’t let you override the PostCSS configuration natively, we also need to install CRACO to be able to configure Tailwind. But somehow **craco** is not installed on your project.

*So we have to do is :*

```
npm install @craco/craco
```

OR

```
npm install @craco/craco --save
```

Comment: --save has no effect from npm 5 its added as  by default

Answer (score 2):

make sure `craco` if you cant use this command

```
npm install @craco/craco --legacy-peer-deps
```

make sure **craco.config.js** to be like this

```
// craco.config.js
module.exports = {
    style: {
       postOptions: {
        plugins: [
          require('tailwindcss'),
          require('autoprefixer'),
        ],
      },
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check @craco/craco version in package.json file

```
  npm install @craco/craco@5.8 --save
              OR 
  yarn add @craco/craco@5.8
```

5.8 is a version of craco in package.json file.

and close editor and reopen try to run